# How to run setup once for several "scenarios" in Rails Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec2, poltergeist

Related to question: [how to run capybara commands once, then run some tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371605/how-to-run-capybara-commands-once-then-run-some-tests)

How do I set up a Capybara test to run part of the background just once and have the database records there for the scenarios in the test.

Note, I'm using database_cleaner between tests. Yes, I have some seed_tables, but I'd like to have a scope that is not global but just one file of integration tests.

```
feature "some feature" do
background do
 # set up some records that don't change between scenarios

 # set up some records that do change between scenarios
end

scenario "scenario 1" do
  # run tests
end

scenario "scenario 2" do
  # run tests
end
end
```

Here's my setup for database_cleaner.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.add_setting(:seed_tables)
  config.seed_tables = %w(global_options shoot_types)

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, except: config.seed_tables)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {except: config.seed_tables}
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

As you may know `background` is an alias of `before` for feature tests (see [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec/features.rb#L5)). So, you can use:

```
background(:all) do
  # set up some records that don't change between scenarios
end

background(:each) do # or background
  # set up some records that do change between scenarios
end
```